# Passing a Custom jQuery class to Spring Controller

Tags: java, jquery, spring-mvc

I have created a object and added to an Array in Jquery as below

```
function CharacterData(name,value,type) {
    this.name = name;
    this.value = value;
    this.type = type;
}

var characters = new Array();
characters[0]=new CharacterData("0","1","2");
characters[1]=new CharacterData("0","1","2");
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "xxyyzz.action",
    data: {
        characters:characters
    },
    success:function(response) {
        alert("GOOD");
    }
});
```

Now I need to pass this value to my Spring MVC Controller as below

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "xxyyzz.action", method = {RequestMethod.POST})
public MyClass getxxyyzzPage(
        final CharacterDataList characters) {
            return null;
        }
```

The POJOs are as below

```
 public class CharacterDataList {

    private List<CharacterData> characterData;

    public List<CharacterData> getCharacterData() {
        return characterData;
    }

    public void setCharacterData(
            final List<CharacterData> characterData) {
        this.characterData = characterData;
    }
}
```

Next one

```
public class CharacterData {

    private String name, value, type;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(final String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(final String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

But in the controller I am getting "characters!=null" but  "characters.characterData=null". Please let me know how to pass these values ?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need the CharacterDataList.  I believe the problem is that the de-marshaller is looking for a value "characters" that has a member "characterData".  You have an array of "characters" that just has a bunch of objects that happen to be of type CharacterData.

Have you tried changing your Controller method to just be an List?

Comment: Thanks for your reply... List of what type?

Comment: I would do a List<CharacterData>

Comment: I got a exception saying List cannot be instantiated :(